# Continuous percentile as x-axis

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I'm looking to create a visualization that the x-axis is a continuous percentile from 0-100. And then a metric on the y-axis.

As an example all of the temperatures in a month on the y-axis and the percentile of that reading on the x-axis.

Similar to the graph shown in this example (Can not post the image directly as I do not have enough reputation points):

[image: https://truelearn.com/Percentile.png]

Comment: What does your data look like

Comment: I can't provide you the data I'm working with, but if it would help I can create a sample dataset with a list of "temperatures"?